# How would you translate "Full-stack engineer"?

Tags: traduction, informatique, professions

A full-stack engineer is an I.T. engineer that is knowledgeable in all fields concerning the conception, development and deployment of software projects and especially web projects (As opposed to a front-end engineer, back-end engineer or systems engineer). A good definition can be found [here](http://www.laurencegellert.com/2012/08/what-is-a-full-stack-developer/)

I have been trying to translate this word into french, but I can't find the right translation for the word stack, as in application stack.

(This might be a little too technical, I have never been on this SE website before, so apologies in advance if it is!)

Comment: The usual french term for _stack_ in computer science is _pile_. This is the first time I encounter the term _full-stack_ with that usage. A quick search on Google reveals that job offerings don't bother and use the _Full-Stack_ term directly: _Ingénieur Full-Stack_, _Développeur Full-Stack_, _Lead-Développeur Full-Stack_.

Comment: That's what I've settled with for now. I'm guessing a direct translation that conveys the same meaning would be "ingénieur toutes couches", but there's no way I'm writing that in an official document :D

Comment: I agree that _Ingénieur toutes couches_ is a bit... smelly.  :P

Comment: *multi-couches* maybe ? Doesn't convey the meaning of *all* but I guess it won't be a matter here. As a side note, I'm afraid I can't do a thing about your *smelly* mind association ^^

Comment: What about the common "Ingénieur Concepteur Développeur (ICD)" aren't they `full-stack` by definition?

Comment: IMHO _Ingénieur Concepteur Développeur (ICD)_ just like _Analyste-Programmeur_, is not strong enough, as _Full-Stack_ includes deployment, integration, database, UI and such. Just like _multi-couches_, as @RomainVALERI pointed out.

Comment: I guess this is one of the many terms that will end up someday in the french dictionary untranslated for lack of a meaningful translation (like *selfie* for example!).

Comment: Si on regarde cette fiche de pole-emploi([M1805](http://candidat.pole-emploi.fr/marche-du-travail/fichemetierrome?codeRome=M1805)), dans la section "appellations métiers", on voit d'où plusieurs tirent leur inspiration. J'ai vu par exemple le _ICD_ avec _R&D_ etc.

Comment: What about `auto-suffisant` or `autoportant`? Or some way of indicating that one could, in theory, do every single part oneself, except perhaps for meeting the deadlines of course. "Je suis un ingénieur web `autonome`". I can't really nail it either but perhaps these attempts will reveal a better answer hidden away in one of my readers' minds.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that the referenced [Full Stack Developer](http://www.laurencegellert.com/2012/08/what-is-a-full-stack-developer/) definition simply describes a software developer mastering current & fashionable *web technologies*.
A developer is not necessarily an engineer, not necessarily an architect.
Therefore, I would simply translate as "développeur technologies web".
If the job requires it, use "ingénieur confirmé technologies web" or even "ingénieur technologies web très confirmé".

In any case, "Full Stack Developer" is just a buzzword. You can as well translate it as "développeur Full Stack", everybody will recognize the buzzword...

Comment: In this case, what is the word "confirmé" referring to? Even as a native french speaker I'm not sure. Does it mean that you are a member of the "Order of Engineers" or any other official organisation that certifies you as an engineer? Or perhaps it means that you have a lot of experience? As you pointed out, I would also recommend that people who are not ngeneers (like me) don't call themselves as such and use "développeur" instead on "ingénieur".

Answer (score 2):

A couple of ideas:

- ingénieur généraliste
- ingénieur polyvalent

Comment: The only problem with this translation is that it implies that the engineer is knowledgeable in all engineering fields whereas a full-stack engineer is knowledgeable only in the IT field, not in physics or say, thermonuclear reactors!

Comment: But we could say "ingénieur informaticien polyvalent". Although it sounds kinda cheap it conveys the same meaning.

Comment: ingénieur web généraliste?

Answer (score -1):

You may want to see the "stack" in french as a "cycle" because in software development if you traverse the full stack you actually made a cycle in the development or running of the project (especially if you work with iterations).

So I was thinking of something like

- Ingénieur cycle complet
- Ingénieur cycle de vie complet

but that doesn't "sounds good" in french.

Comment: I wouldn't really translate it as "cycle". A stack is the set of technology layers that a software product is made out of. *Full stack* means you have sufficient skill to work with all these technologies. There is no notion of temporality (unlike in *lifecycle*) about a stack, it's a static range of layers.

Comment: @guillaume31 you are right and I was aware of it when posting. But I never heard about "ingénieur pile complete" in french. So, IMHO, the notion of the complet stack was described fairly enough by the word "cycle". I'm curious about how correctly translating it in french.

Comment: Like many technical terms in IT, the word has been picked up and used as is, it's probably too late for a french translation now ;)