# Comment traduire front-end et back-end ?

Tags: informatique, terminologie

Dans le contexte des systèmes informatiques multicouches, comment traduit-on *front-end* et *back-end* en francais ?

J'ai cherché un peu sur le net mais je n'ai pas trouvé de réponse satisfaisante. D'autant plus que Wikipédia en français utilise les termes anglais [*backend*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backend) et *frontend*. C'est peut-être mieux (ou acceptable) d'utiliser les mots anglais ?

Comment: Les seuls moments où j'ai vu chercher des alternatives plus visiblement française à _frontend_ et _backend_, c'est lors de la rédaction de rapports de stage, et les propositions semblent toujours artificielles, car ne correspondant à aucun usage. (Je travaille pour une société américaine et donc les documents internes techniques sont toujours en anglais; il y a peut-être des termes consacrés utilisés dans des contextes moins soumis à l'influence de l'anglais).

Comment: Back-Office & Front Office nouveaux mots: http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do;jsessionid=?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000029461191&dateTexte=&oldAction=dernierJO&categorieLien=id

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dans le jargon informatique, on utilise couramment **[frontal](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frontal_(serveur))** pour ***front-end***, par exemple « **deux serveurs frontaux** ».

Pour ***back-end***, la terminologie anglaise est souvent reprise mais on rencontre aussi **interne**, **arrière** ou **principal**.

Wikipedia propose **[en arrière-plan](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backend)**  mais cette expression peut parfois porter à confusion, **arrière-plan** étant déjà utilisé pour traduire ***background***.

Comment: @Paolo pourra toujours clarifier mais il ne s'agit pas forcément de _serveurs_: On peut dire _front/back end engineer_

Comment: La question indique « systèmes informatiques multi-couches » ce qui implique pour moi matériel et logiciels. Un *front-end engineer* me parait plutôt être un ingénieur avant-vente.

Comment: Tiré de l'article wikipedia cité en référence: _Dans un environnement client-serveur, on considère que le client fait office de front-end alors que le serveur fait office de back-end._

Comment: Quand à _ingénieur avant-vente_, je n'ai jamais entendu ce terme et j'ai pris le temps consulter [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ing%C3%A9nieur+avant-vente&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) qui semble être assez d'accord..

Comment: [Cette question](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8538/how-would-you-translate-full-stack-engineer/11794#11794) est quelque peu reliée

Comment: @Mina Un ingénieur avant-vente ([pre-sales engineer](http://www.pragmaticmarketing.com/resources/the-role-of-sales-engineer-in-technical-sales)), c'est quelqu'un de formation technique qui interagit avec des clients potentiels, par exemple pour analyser les besoins concernant un produit qui doit être adapté à chaque client. Cela n'a rien à voir avec la distinction front-end/back-end.

Comment: Merci d'eclairer ma lanterne @Gilles

Comment: @mina ngram ignore les expressions établies qui ne sont pas encore entrés dans la littérature. Dans le doute, il ne faut pas hésiter à faire une recherche plus élargie avec un moteur de recherche classique. Le premier lien trouvé par google par exemple est http://www.cadresonline.com/conseils/coaching/fiches-metiers-salaires/fiches-metiers/detail/article/ingenieur-avant-vente.html qui correspond plus ou moins à cette définition du *front-end engineer* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front-end_engineering

Comment: @jlliagre Le premier lien trouvé par google change d'une personne à une autre: celui que vous avez posté n'apparait pas dans ma première page alors que le deuxième si.

Comment: Mais cela ne change rien au fait que je ne pense pas que ce soit ce à quoi fait allusion la question puisque _front end_ y est associé à _back end_ donc je pense qu'il s'agit plutot de [cette definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_End_Development) qui est citée comme autre possibilité dans votre deuxième lien.

Comment: @mina Il est vrai que le premier lien trouvé change avec l'utilisateur mais je répondais à "je n'ai jamais entendu ce terme et j'ai pris le temps consulter ngram qui semble être assez d'accord." Pour ce qui est de savoir à quelle définition la question fait allusion, le mieux est d'attendre que Paolo éclaire notre lanterne.

Comment: @jiliagre, Chez nous les _front-end engineers_ c'est une classification indépendantes des _pre-sales engineers_ (les quatres possibilités existent)

Comment: @Mina enfin le contexte c'est celui des systems, mais en anglais on peut bien trouver front-end developer ou front-end engineer pour indiquer quelq'un spécialisé dans le front-end.  Je utiliserais les mot anglais car je vois pas une vrais bonne traduction :D

Comment: Interne est le terme qui me semble le plus *exact*. Arrière-plan est effectivement trop près de "background" et principal ne transmet pas cette idée de "backend". Merci!

Answer (score 5):

**Back-end**: Partie serveur, partie logique métier.

**Front-end**: Partie client, partie interface.

Comment: Clair et précis comme réponse !

Answer (score 2):

*Termium* (la banque de terminologie du Bureau de la traduction du gouvernement du Canada) propose *programme secondaire* pour [*back-end (program)*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=ent&__index=ent&srchtxt=BACK+END+PROGRAM).

Comment: Termium (et surtout Termium Plus) n'est pas nécessairement d'accès général. J'y ai accès depuis un réseau interne du gouvernement. Si la page BACK-END vous est accessible, tant mieux !

Comment: J'utilise ce site tous les jours depuis plusieurs ordinateurs différents, et je n'ai jamais eu de problème. Ne s'agit-il pas plutôt d'un problème de filtrage? Pour la France, http://www.culture.fr/franceterme est plus adapté quoique beaucoup (et de loin) moins riche.

Answer (score 1):

L'Office québécois de la langue française propose ce qui suit :

---

Développeur d'applications frontales (Front-End Developer)
Domaines : Informatique > logiciel

Appellation de personne et appellation d'emploi.

Auteur : Office québécois de la langue française, 2017

Définition : Spécialiste chargé de créer et de coder l'interface visuelle d'une application ou d'un site Web de façon à ce qu'elle soit simple et facile d'utilisation pour un utilisateur final.

Note : Le développeur d'applications frontales est chargé d'adapter les applications et les sites Web aux besoins des usagers. Il travaille en étroite collaboration avec le développeur d'applications dorsales, qui s'occupe des bases logicielles.

Termes privilégiés :

développeur d'applications frontales   n. m., 
développeuse d'applications frontales   n. f.

---

Développeur d'applications dorsales (Back-End Developer)
Domaines :nformatique > logiciel

Appellation de personne > appellation d'emploi

Auteur : Office québécois de la langue française, 2017

Définition : Spécialiste chargé de la configuration, du développement et de la maintenance d'une application ou d'un site Web.

Note : Le développeur d'applications dorsales s'occupe des bases logicielles. Il travaille en étroite collaboration avec le développeur d'applications frontales, chargé d'adapter les applications et les sites Web aux besoins des usagers.

Termes privilégiés :

Développeur d'applications dorsales   n. m., 
Développeuse d'applications dorsales   n. f.

Answer (score 0):

Des transpositions françaises de ces termes qui conviennent et qui sont aisément intelligibles sont les suivantes:

**Front-End:** développement interface utilisateur

**Back-End:** développement d'arrière-scène