# « Merci full ! » : de quel sens de l'emprunt (intégral) de « full » s'agit-il, quels francophones l'utilisent en registre familier etc. ?

Tags: adverbes, origine-ou-raison, anglicismes, emprunts

On félicite une Québécoise qui s'est méritée un prix pour son œuvre et elle [répond](http://www.lapresse.ca/arts/201804/11/01-5160705-la-quebecoise-zoe-pelchat-primee-pour-sa-webserie-a-cannes.php) « *Merci full !* ». Il ne s'agit pas de l'emprunt [*full*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/full) (*house/hand*) pour le jeu de cartes (poker), mais bien d'un emploi de *certains francophones* (BDL), qu'on trouverait en [adjectif](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/full#Adjectif) (*le train est full, c'est full*) pour *bondé, plein* (Wiktionnaire), et en emploi [adverbial](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/full#Adverbe) et familier (*la personne est full gentille*) pour *très, vraiment, au maximum* (Wiktionnaire). Le *GPCF* d'il y a un  peu moins d'un siècle ne réfère qu'à *full-dress* (*avoir mis son...* : s'être vêtu de ses meilleurs habits).

---

- Ce *merci full*, c'est merci *beaucoup, mille fois, sincèrement* : lequel ; peut-on expliquer s'il s'agit d'un [intensificateur](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=full&T3.x=0&T3.y=0&id=2790), est-ce le degré ou la nature/manière ; peut-on changer la position de l'adverbe (*full merci*), est-ce un [anglicisme intégral](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=3787) ?
- C'est d'un registre familier, peut-on préciser ; est-ce
  employé/compris partout au Québec, qui sont ces « certains francophones », y a-t-il une connotation particulière ?
- D'où vient cet emploi de *full*, pourquoi ce mot semble-t-il si malléable en français du Québec (pourquoi pas, *a lot, a bunch, tons,
  total* etc.), depuis quand à peu près est-ce employé et à quel besoin répond-il/à quoi sert-il ou quelle nuance cet emprunt introduirait-il comparativement à un autre adverbe, hormis celle du registre ?

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour,

De mon point de vue de francophone française, c'est purement un emprunt à l'anglais. Chez nous, on l'utilise dans deux cas différents : dans un registre technique, notamment en informatique. Par exemple, "ce sera une solution full Java" pour dire que l'application sera réalisée intégralement à l'aide de ce langage de programmation. Dans ce contexte, c'est souvent pour donner un côté professionnel ou mercatique lorsque l'on veut décrire un procédé particulier.

Pour ma part, je l'entends plus dans un cadre informel, où l'on s'en sert pour accentuer une caractéristique ("Je l'ai fait en full improvisation", c'est à dire j'ai tout improvisé sur le moment, "J'ai passé une soirée full révisions", c'est à dire j'ai passé toute la soirée à réviser).
En France, le fait d'utiliser des anglicisme ou des emprunts est souvent considéré comme ou bien technique (en informatique, en sciences humaines...) ou bien informel.

J'espère que ma réponse vous éclaire un peu. :) Après, j'ai bien conscience que le rapport aux mots d'anglais n'est pas le même en France et au Québec, mais j'ai pensé que ce point de vue particulier pourrait vous intéresser dans le cadre de votre question.

Comment: Merci ! Je connais en partie les emplois tech., v. aussi [_full-stack_](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/8538/3177), en pensant à _full_, je pense à _full on, full price, full featured, full metal jacket, full-court press,_ et ngram l'associe à _employment, moon, length, force, speed, extent, power_ etc. Parfois ça semble servir à ajouter de l'intensité à qqc. qui vient ensuite qualifier qqc. d'autre. Pensez-vous que l'emploi plus usuel vient de celui plus technique ? Prononce-t-on comme _foule_ ? Vos emprunts sont-ils morpho-s. intégraux ? Qu'entendez-vs. de merci full, de la pos. de full ?

Comment: Ce n'est pas un anglicisme, on ne dirait pas *"*thank you full*"

Comment: @qoba Effectivment, ce n'est pas un anglicisme, mais plutôt un emprunt. :)

Comment: @floquonsd'oùpepperx Oui, j'avais pensé à full-stack aussi, mais dans ce cas, c'est toute l'expression qui est reprise, pas seulement le "full". En France, on le prononce bien "foule". Je ne suis pas sûre que l'emploi usuel dérive du technique.Je pense que cela vient du fait que nous lisons de plus en plus d'anglais (internet, réseaux sociaux...) et que nous faisons de moins en moins l'effort de traduire quand notre cerveau évoque d'abord le mot "full" suite à ce que nous avons lu et entendu sur internet. La sonorité doit aussi y être pour qqch, d'où l'emploi préferentiel aux bunch of, tons of

Answer (score 1):

Une élève d'un de mes collègues lui a déjà dit que la salle de concert était "full vide." Donc, "full" semble remplacer parfois, au Québec, "très" ou "complètement".

Comment: Merci, c'est un peu protéiforme, _très_ est déjà énoncé en question, vous ajoutez _complètement_, on avait _au maximum_ au Wiktionnaire etc. Je connais même _je veux full_ tout court. Mais _merci full_ selon vous c'est merci beaucoup ou merci complètement, y a-t-il une différence selon vous et celui-là traite-t-il d'autre chose que de l'intensité ?

Answer (score 1):

*Full* au Québec, en langue populaire, est emprunté à l'anglais comme adverbe pour accentuer ou intensifier quelque chose [1](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2790).

Il ne correspond souvent pas à un usage du même mot en anglais, par exemple dans *full cute*, le sens du mot *full* est incompréhensible en anglais, ou au moins son usage est incorrect, mais l'expression a le sens de *très mignon* en français du Québec. Pour cela il se rapproche plus de l'emprunt que de l'anglicisme, à mon avis.

Je n'ai pas de source étymologique, mais une hypothèse à proposer. D'abord un fait intéressant : le mot *full* est emprunté avec un sens similaire d'intensif multi-usages dans l'espagnol de Puerto Rico et de la République Dominicaine [2](https://m.facebook.com/notes/fourth-chakra/diccionario-mal-educado-puertorrique%C3%B1o/400324016747222/). Je me demande si ce mot, faisant partie de ceux qui sont les plus utiles à la communication avec les anglophones, par exemple pour faire le plein d'essence en voiture, commence par être utilisé en anglais par des allophones avec un sens plus large que les anglophones lui donneraient par manque de vocabulaire anglais, puis revient dans la langue maternelle avec le nouveau sens "élargi".

Comment: ...ce serait la substantivation du suffixe [-ful](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/-ful) de certains mots en anglais pour _full of/characterized by_, comme _beautiful, shameful, sinful, graceful, thankful_. Ça créerait un apport à définir, à défaut de signifier que _merci full_ veuille dire exactement _plein de_... gratitude. Selon moi c'est merci bcp mais avec un apport particulier, dont le registre... d'où la question. Merci !

Comment: Ah oui merci je n'avais pas vu le lien dans la question... Concernant *full* vs *fill up*, la fréquence de *full* en anglais est un peu plus élevée que *fill* et beaucoup plus élevée que *fill up*, d'où il serait raisonnable que *full* fasse preuve de substitut par défaut pour tous les mots se rapprochant à l'idée de remplir ou de complétude. Il y a aussi peut-être un phénomène similaire avec le français du Maghreb où *direct* finit par vouloir dire *tout droit*.

Comment: Je ne pense pas trop au suffixe *-ful* par contre, dont l'emploi pour former des mots est relativement infréquent même en anglais (par exemple beaucoup d'anglophones préféreront *by the bucket* à *by the bucketful*)

Comment: Merci, oui peut-être, mais _beautiful_ n'est certainement pas un mot inusité et à mon avis c'est certainement un mot qu'un apprenant s'approprie dès le départ. Au final je ne sais pas si le vecteur c'est le technique, l'usuel, voire le religieux... Si plus tard vous étayez cette hypothèse intéressante dont vous parliez ou trouvez qqc. d'autre n'hésitez pas à revenir là-dessus. Merci !